# Make an existing website responsive

Tags: responsive-design

As an assignment for school we had to make a website but we couldn't touch the HTML except for adding classes and id's.

Now my website is almost done but when people on bigger or smaller resolutions open te site everything is different because it's not responsive. Now we can use a grid even tough they didn't explain how that works.

is there a way to make my existing site responsive?

Comment: Google is your friend. There are hundreds of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Only adding classes and ID's isn't enough... You'll have to include at least one CSS file to pull this off.

Hint: Use media-queries if you want to do everything yourself. If you're looking into using an existing CSS framework that handles responsive websites pretty well, I'd suggest looking at UIKit (http://getuikit.com/)

Comment: I'm verry sorry for not mentioning this but i have indeed 2 css files already linked. 1 called Home (where i did all the coding) and 1 called grid but that's empty at the moment.

Comment: So your assignment consists of filling the grid.css file with media-queries ;)

This should point you in the right direction: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Look for the media-query example code. Note the different max-width settings.

Comment: thanks alot Harold i will definitely look into this. Greetings from Belgium